# Error when make the objects both MoveLeft and Spinning in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make objects **fly to the left while spinning themselves**.

Here is the *MoveLeft* script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveLeft : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float moveLeftSpeed = 10;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * moveLeftSpeed);
    }
    
}
```

And there is the *SpinObjects* script:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpinObjectsX : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float spinSpeed = 50;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, Time.deltaTime * spinSpeed, 0));
    }
}
```

[image: I expect the object's movement will look like this.]

I expect the object's movement will look like this, it just moves to the left and spins itself.

[image: But when I use both scripts, the object moves very weird, it is still spinning itself but instead of moving to the left, it spinning around something...]

But when I use both scripts, the object moves very weirdly, it is still spinning itself but instead of moving to the left, it spins around something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [`Translate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) and [`Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) per default work in **local space** of according object unless you explicitly pass in [`Space.World`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Space.World.html) as additional last parameter.

So, after rotating your object around the Y-axis it's local `left` vector is now rotated as well and pointing somewhere else.

=> When you do the **local space** translation towards left of the object it doesn't actually move left in the world.

In order to move left in absolute world space you want to use

```
transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * moveLeftSpeed, Space.World);
```